# How to load Activity without animation (like tabs in TabHost load activities) on Android?

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, tabs

I've set up a `TabHost` containing a `TabWiget` with three tabs in it - each of which loads a separate activity. This all works well, switching between them is smooth, state drawables on tabs work well and so on.

However, in each activity (i.e. tab contents) I need to load further activities while still showing the tab bar at the top. Problem is, doing this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
```

loads the activity, but with a sliding animation. This looks weird when I'm supposed to have a fixed tab bar at the top (i.e. it slides out and back in). Switching activities with the tabs does not trigger this animation.

How can I load an activity without the sliding animation? I have no problem doing it through the `TabHost` if that's required, but its API didn't suggest this was possible.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ActivityGroup` for the tab contents, and then managing their content with `getLocalActivityManager` seems to be the trick: http://blog.henriklarsentoft.com/2010/07/android-tabactivity-nested-activities/